# Why doesn't $(".tab-list").each() run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The idea is a simple html tab.

https://codepen.io/ryboh1/pen/abzGEJj

```
$(".tab-list").each( () => {
    $("#p").html("hello")    
    /* for each tab-list*/
    let $this = $(this);
    let $tab = $this.find("li.active");
    let $link = $tab.find("a");
    let $panel = $($link.attr("href"));

    /*When Clicked on a tab add this function*/
    $this.on("click", "tab-control", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let $link = $(this);
        let id = this.hash;


        if (id && !$link.is("active")) {
            $panel.removeClass("active");
            $tab.removeClass("active");


        $panel = $(id).addClass("active");
        $tab = $link.parent().addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

When you click a tab the content changes.

I've tried using Chrome dev tools and copied and pasted the first line  of the js and it ran. Which confuses me.
any help would be appreciated

Comment: First off it looks like you are missing the `.` at the class selector in `$this.on("click", "tab-control", (e) => {`

Comment: Arrow functions doesn't have own `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ass Ritesh says, arrow function don't have `this`, so if you wish you can convert `() => {}` to `function() {}`. Also you are missing the `.` in `"tab-control"`

**Working example**

```js
$(".tab-list").each(function() {
  $("#p").html("hello")
  /* for each tab-list*/
  let $this = $(this);
  let $tab = $this.find("li.active");
  let $link = $tab.find("a");
  let $panel = $($link.attr("href"));
  /*When Clicked on a tab add this function*/
  $this.on("click", ".tab-control", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $link = $(this);
    let id = this.hash;


    if (id && !$link.is("active")) {
      $panel.removeClass("active");
      $tab.removeClass("active");


      $panel = $(id).addClass("active");
      $tab = $link.parent().addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Create page*/

.create {
  bottom: 75px;
  top: 75px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: large;
  width: 100px;
}

.tab-panel {
  display: none;
}

.tab-panel.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container create position-absolute">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-3">
      <ul class="list-group headings tab-list">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-goal" class="tab-control">Goal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-response" class="tab-control">Response</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-reward" class="tab-control">Reward</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-cue" class="tab-control">Cue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-craving" class="tab-control">Craving</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-preview" class="tab-control">Preview + Create</a></li>
        <ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9">
      <form onsubmit="theTemplate.submitForm('createForm')" id="createForm" action="GET" class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab-goal" data-tab-content class="active form-group tab-panel">
          <h1>Goal</h1>
          <label>What is your desired outcome?</label>
          <input name="goalOne" type="text" class="form-control">
          <label>What type of person achieves that outcome?</label>
          <input name="goalTwo" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div id="tab-response" data-tab-content class="form-group tab-panel">
          <h1>Response</h1>
          <label>What habit does this type of person have?</label>
          <input name="responseOne" type="text" class="form-control">
          <p>List what you could do for the first 2 minutes of this new habit, from very easy to very difficult.</p>
          <table name="responseTwo" class="table-sm">
            <tr>
              <th>Very Easy</th>
              <td><input name="vEasy" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Easy</th>
              <td><input name="easy" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Normal</th>
              <td><input name="normal" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Difficult</th>
              <td><input name="difficult" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Very Difficult</th>
              <td><input name="vDifficult" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div id="tab-reward" data-tab-content class="tab-panel">
          <h1>Reward</h1>
          <label>What can you keep track of to measure your progress?</label>
          <input name="rewardTwo" type="text" class="form-control">
          <label>What will you use to track your progress?</label>
          <input name="rewardOne" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div id="tab-cue" data-tab-content class="tab-panel">
          <h1>Cue</h1>
          <label>How can you design your enviroment to make it obivous to do your new habit?</label>
          <input name="cueOne" type="text" class="form-control">
          <label>Which established habit will you do before your new habit?</label>
          <input name="cueTwo" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div id="tab-craving" data-tab-content class="tab-panel">
          <h1>Craving</h1>
          <label>How can you re-frame your new habit to make it seem more attractive?</label>
          <input name="cravingOne" type="text" class="form-control">
          <label>What habit you want to do, will you do after your new habit?</label>
          <input name="cravingTwo" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div id="tab-preview" data-tab-content class="tab-panel">
          <h1>Preview + Save Habit</h1>
          <label for="">To download your cheat sheet click Preview Habit</label>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Preview Habit</button>
          <lab for="">To save your habit to "Habit List", to download later click Save Habit.</lab>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Habit</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah I didn't know that thank you very much. 
Why wasn't it running the .each loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you bind after document is ready and maybe just bind directly to each with class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab-list").bind("click",function(event) {
      this...
```